# Android custom keyboard orientation symbol/qwerty

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, sample

I am using android **sample softkeyboard** as a learning project. I have added a second language and all is working fine for me so far. One problem, however, I found hard to solve. On changing device's orientation from portrait to landscape I would like whatever keybord layout is on to stay on. the logic would be:

```
 // on orientation or configuration change
if (currentKeyboard==mQwertyKeyboard) {
          // keep as is
            mCurKeyboard = mQwertyKeyboard ;   
 }else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsKeyboard) {
          // keep as is
            mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsKeyboard;
}else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) {
          // keep as is
            mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard ; 
 }
```

I have tried to implement this in:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {...}
```

inside Softkeyboard.java, but to no fruition. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your questions here? Please post it if you got something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem - I solved it by using `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` and a little of side coding

If it is removed, my code would change orientation but my keyboard would not be resized. Since I love the re-sizing feature of the parent, I made an array that contains all the keyboards and after changing orientation, I would update the array so that the keyboard array would have the right sizes.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    int currentKeyboard = 0;
    boolean isShifted = kv.isShifted();
    for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length; i++) {
        if(kv.getKeyboard().equals(keyboard[i])){
            currentKeyboard = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    initializeKeyboardArray();
    setKeyboard(keyboard[currentKeyboard]);
    kv.setShifted(isShifted);

}

private void initializeKeyboardArray(){
    keyboard = new Keyboard[7];
    keyboard[ARABIC] = arabic;
    keyboard[ARABIC_SHIFT] = arabicShift;
    keyboard[ARABIC_SYMBOLS] = arabicSymbols;
    keyboard[ARABIC_SYMBOLS_SHIFT] = arabicSymbolsShift;
    keyboard[QWERTY] = qwerty;
    keyboard[QWERTY_SYMBOLS] = qwertySymbols;
    keyboard[QWERTY_SYMBOLS_SHIFT] = qwertySymbolsShift;
}
```